# Shelf life of Sesame Oil?

Tags: storage-lifetime

I love the taste of sesame oil, I can easily go through an 8 ounce bottle in a couple of weeks if I'm on an Asian kick, an 8 ounce bottle of my favorite brand has never lasted more than a couple of months. Right now, Amazon is offering a 56 ounce metal jug of *my favorite brand* of sesame oil for less than 3 times the price I pay at the grocery store for an eight ounce bottle. Ounce for ounce it's a great deal, no shipping costs even. Can I make an open jug last a year? My thinking is to transfer 8-12 ounces at a time into a glass bottle and keep the metal jug in the back of the fridge where things have the tendency to freeze. Is that the best way to handle it? Should I get the bulk of it out of the metal and into glass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [StillTasty](http://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/17807), you should get at least one year, refrigerated.

They note it may become cloudy and solidify, but that this does not affect quality.  Allowing it to come to room temperature will bring it back to a liquid state.

Comment: That's what I need to know! I'm about to become the proud owner of a year's worth of sesame oil! *Party!*